# How to Disable Edit Button based a particular value & specific user role in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I really need some assistance with this query. Have been trying with no success. This is the scenario and query:

I have a form with info, what I want to accomplish is to disable  the edit mode (**Edit Link Button**) based on  particular dropdownlist (ItemStatus) values, that is:
When **ItemStatus** is *Broken* || *Discarded* && **UserRole** not in ('*Sys Admin*' || '*App Admin*') User should not be able to edit the form.

Attempted the first aspect of it, that is **ItemStatus** and can still ****Edit**** the form when **Edit** is clicked. Appreciate the help.

Aspx:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Status" SortExpression="ItemStatus">
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ItemStatusEd" runat="server" DataSourceID="ItemStatusEdDS" 
         DataTextField="ItemStatus" DataValueField=" ItemStatus" selectedvalue='<%# Bind("Status") %>' > 
      </asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StatusEdRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ItemStatusEd" ErrorMessage="Item Statusis Required" ForeColor="Red" 
         ValidationGroup="RecEd">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   </EditItemTemplate>
   <InsertItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ItemStatusIns" runat="server" DataSourceID="ItemStatusDS"
         DataTextField="ItemStatus" DataValueField="ItemStatus"
         selectedvalue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'  AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="190px">
         <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="">Select Item Status</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StatusInsRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="StatusIns" 
         ErrorMessage="Item Status is Required" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="RecIns">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   </InsertItemTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ItemStatusEdDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PMAConStr %>" 
   SelectCommand="select [ID], [ItemStatus] from [ItemStatusTbl] where ([Status] = 'A')">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The Code Behind (C#) :

```
if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
{
    try
    {
        DropDownList ItemStatusEd = new DropDownList();
        StatusEd = (DropDownList)ItemInfoDet.FindControl("ItemStatusEd"); /* without these 2 lines of code here it will not find the control ItemStatusEd*/

        if (ItemStatusEd.SelectedValue == "Condemned/Scrapped" || ItemStatusEd.SelectedValue == "Written Off")
        {
            ItemStatusEd.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ItemStatusEd.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "<img src='../Stylesheet/images/warning.gif' alt='Error!' width='24' height='24' style='float: left; margin: -5px 10px 0px 0px; ' /> <span style='font-weight:bold;   color:Red;' >" + exc.Message + "</span> <br />";
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the enable/disable code work now? you  can test for membership with If Roles.IsUserInRole("Staff") Then bla bla bla

Comment: `DropDownList ItemStatusEd = new DropDownList();` Here you instantiate a blank dropdownlist, `StatusEd = (DropDownList)ItemInfoDet.FindControl("ItemStatusEd");` and here you use it to find your dropdownlist, however, the code that follows uses the blank dropdownlist `if (ItemStatusEd.SelectedValue == "Condemned/Scrapped" || ItemStatusEd.`. It looks like you are using the wrong variable for disabling and checking the selectedvalue

Comment: I tested this, it works, was able to disable the edit button for one status, would like to include two statuses: <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" 
                                Enabled='<%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "Condemned/Scrapped" ? false : true %>'></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thanks. I tried something and it worked to an extent……. In the codes below the  visible property works with ShowButtonBasedOnRole() functions. And the enable property works by itself. However the 2 properties and the function does not work together, in that the ‘Visible’ property over-rules the ‘enable’ property. There are no error messages. Help! To have the 2 work together. In aspx...Visible='<%# (bool) ShowButtonBasedOnRole() %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "Condemned/Scrapped" ? false : true %>'

Comment: C#     protected bool ShowButtonBasedOnRole()
       {
            
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Application Admin"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
       }